# Error blogdown::serve_site academic template

Tags: hugo, blogdown

I have recently started to get an error using blogdown to build my website. I am using the academic template, and the error started after I reinstalled blogdown a few days ago to deal with the fact that the academic template started using Hugo modules. The build command works fines, and I can deploy the website with no further errors.

The error:

```
blogdown::serve_site()
Error in !server$daemon : invalid argument type
```

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5       bookdown_0.20    digest_0.6.26    later_1.1.0.1   
 [5] R6_2.4.1         jsonlite_1.7.0   magrittr_1.5     evaluate_0.14   
 [9] blogdown_0.21.22 rlang_0.4.8      promises_1.1.1   rstudioapi_0.11 
[13] rmarkdown_2.3    tools_4.0.2      servr_0.18       httpuv_1.5.4    
[17] xfun_0.18        yaml_2.2.1       compiler_4.0.2   htmltools_0.5.0 
[21] knitr_1.29
```

And my hugo version

```
> blogdown::hugo_version()
[1] ‘0.76.5’
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **servr** package is not the latest version. You need to install the latest version:

```r
install.packages('servr')
```

Or [update all packages](https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/):

```r
update.packages(ask = FALSE)
```

Comment: I don't think this fixes it really.

Comment: Your problem is different: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68145757/559676

Comment: Thank you for looking at my problem! I tried your suggestion but didn't seem to work. I pushed my changes so you can see the repo