# R Blogdown serve site: Error in !server$daemon : invalid argument type

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown

My website used to work fine in my previous laptop, which used R 3.6.3. In my new laptop when I run `blogdown::serve_site()` I get the error `Error in !server$daemon : invalid argument type`. I tried doing what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64544976/error-blogdownserve-site-academic-template) but didn't help.

Here is the session info:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur 11.2.3

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6        bookdown_0.22     digest_0.6.27     later_1.2.0       R6_2.5.0         
 [6] jsonlite_1.7.2    magrittr_2.0.1    evaluate_0.14     blogdown_1.3.2    rlang_0.4.11     
[11] rstudioapi_0.13   promises_1.2.0.1  rmarkdown_2.9     tools_4.1.0       servr_0.22       
[16] httpuv_1.6.1      xfun_0.24         yaml_2.2.1        compiler_4.1.0    htmltools_0.5.1.1
[21] knitr_1.33
```

[This](https://neuralnetworksbristol.netlify.app/) is the website link and you can find the Github repo [here](https://github.com/MauroCE/NeuralNetworksReadingGroup).

Comment: couldn't reproduce. worked just fine here. note that you have a .Rprofile in the repo, so it is overwriting your default profile. Which means, if you're setting a custom lib path in your profile, R session isn't using it. I strongly suggest you to get rid of it.

Comment: @AlbersonMiranda This is what is contained in that file:

`options(
  blogdown.ext = ".Rmd", 
  blogdown.author = "my name",
  blogdown.subdir = "post",
  blogdown.yaml.empty = TRUE,
  servr.daemon = "interactive()",
  blogdown.hugo.version = "0.84.1"
)`

Comment: @AlbersonMiranda I removed the file and it didn't solve the problem. Still get the same error `Error in !server$daemon : invalid argument type`

Answer (score 0):

You should [remove the quotes on `interactive()`](https://github.com/MauroCE/NeuralNetworksReadingGroup/blob/dfb6aaea5d341eaffd23452ff4e967ec2aa4e5a1/.Rprofile#L6). It should be

```r
servr.daemon = interactive()
```

instead of

```r
servr.daemon = "interactive()"
```

Actually `servr.daemon = interactive()` is the default, so you don't really need to set it explicitly (i.e., you can remove this setting).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried 
- Removing the quotes, building the site again and then serving it again. Didn't work.
- Removing `servr.daemon = interactive()` altogether. Didn't work.
I also tried deleting the Rprofile file as suggested in the comment above. That didn't work either. I have pushed my changes

Comment: Then restart R and check the value of `getOption('servr.daemon')`. You may have a global Rprofile in which you set this option value incorrectly.

Comment: Typing that I get `NULL`. What should it be set to?

Comment: `NULL` is okay. What did you mean by "didn't work"? Exactly the same error after you restart R? If you know how to debug R code, here is what you need to inspect: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/blob/00a20903f0b2953f8f350d69bffdcd9c50cda5b1/R/serve.R#L136 I wonder what the value `server$daemon` is.